# Regarding the using expressjs on Apache web server

Tags: apache, node.js, express

Can i use server side scripting language i.e  expressjs on Apache web server for  web site development ..??
Plz suggest tutorial for that any help about that is valuable to me...

Answer (score 0):

Read about [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) and [expressjs](http://expressjs.com).
Node.js is server and Expressjs - web framework under Node.js.
Apache is also web server and you don't need to use them together.
You can place Node.js app behind Nginx or HAproxy if you want.

Comment: thanks for reply , i read it & Yes  your right but in this case i am not use together but i want use Express js web framework on Apache Web server it is possible to use this?? plz reply

Comment: You can start Express.js app on some port and use proxy_pass in Apache to point to your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Node.js app (built with Express or whatever you like) standalone, you don't need to use something in front of it.
If you want to use something in front of it though, I suggest you use something like Nginx better than Apache, since Nginx is also asynchronous (like Node) and it's performs really well at serving static files.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is set node.js as proxy pass inside your site config

here is text on it http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html

Just decided which port to use and which framework :) eg. http://www.expressjs.com